# ODE x'(t)=x(1-x), where it exists

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Solve the following differential equation:
$x'(t)=x(1-x)$**

I see one or two posts with this ODE but i have questions which aren´t answerded there.

I see the trivial solutions $x(t)=1, x(t)=0 \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $.

I define $f(x(t)):=x(1-x) $

I assume that $x(0)=x_0$ with $x_0>0$. Then the largest interval such that $f(x(t))=x(1-x)>0$ is $(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)$.

$ F(x(t)):= \int_{x_0}^{x(t)} \frac{1}{f(y)}= \int_0^t \frac{x'(s)}{f(x(s))} ds = t$

$F(x(t))= \int_{x_0}^x \frac{dy}{y(1-1)}= ln (\frac{x(1-x_0)}{(x_0(1-x)}) $. Now we should find $\phi(t):=F^{-1} (t)$ with $ F(x(t))= ln (\frac{x(1-x_0)}{(x_0(1-x)}) $. Here i became $ \phi(t)= \frac{e^t x_0}{1-x_0 + e^t x_0}$ as a solution of the ODE.

Now we should find $(T_1, T_2)= (lim_{x \downarrow x_1}F(x),lim_{x \uparrow x_2}F(x))  $ to see where F is monoton so that we can inverte F and the solution $\phi(t)$  for $t \in (T_1,T_2) $ exists.
In the case $x_0<1$ I became $(T_1,T_2)=(-\infty, \infty)$. So that $ lim_{t\rightarrow - \infty} \phi(t)=0$ and $ lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\phi(t)=1$.

In the case $x_0>1$ i have $lim_{x \downarrow x_1}F(x)=lim_{x \downarrow 0}ln (\frac{x(1-x_0)}{(x_0(1-x)})= - \infty$ and $lim_{x \uparrow x_1}F(x)=lim_{x \uparrow 1}ln (\frac{x(1-x_0)}{(x_0(1-x)}) $ doesn't exists. This case i don't understand. How the solution look when $x_0>1$ and why the argument like above doesn´t work?

Comment: If you want to see the solution, just plot the graph of $x(t)=1/(1+Ce^{-t})$ for some suitable value of $C$. For example, to get $x_0=2$, take $C=-1/2$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F%281-exp%28-t%29%2F2%29.

Comment: But i want to calculate the solution in the case $x_0>1$! Where and why it goes to $+ \infty$ on the left side? How i see this in my calculation?

Comment: That *is* the solution (as shown in JJacquelin's answer). And from the formula, it's clear that $x(t)$ blows up if and only if $1+Ce^{-t} \to 0$ (which can happen only if $C < 0$).

Answer (score 0):

The ODE is on the separable kind : 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x(1-x)$$
$$dt=\frac{dx}{x(1-x)}$$
$$t=\int \frac{dx}{x(1-x)}=\ln\left|\frac{x}{1-x} \right|+\text{constant}$$
$$e^t=C\frac{x}{1-x}$$
$$x=\frac{1}{1+C\:e^{-t}}$$